# Telerik RadGridView.CommitEdit() StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, edit, radgridview

I currently have a WPF application with a RadGridView control from Telerik.  I have some columns with data from a database, while I have three more custom made columns which are for entering in data.  My problem right now is that once I enter data into a cell within one of the columns, as I click out of that cell the data disappears.  I need to get my application to commit those changes so that doesn't happen.  I thought I had it coded correctly using `gridView.CommitEdit();`within the CellEditEnded event, however a stackoverflow exception is thrown when I enter the data and click out of the cell.  Is anyone able to explain to me why that is and a possible solution to this issue?  I'm having a hard time finding good resources online explaining how to do this.  Below is my code for the CellEditEnded event:

```
private void gridView_CellEditEnded(object sender, GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.EditAction == GridViewEditAction.Commit)
        {
            gridView.CommitEdit();
        }
    }
```

If anyone is able to help me understand what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a boolean flag to prevent the event handler from calling the `CommitEdit()` method over and over again:

```
bool handle = true;
private void gridView_CellEditEnded(object sender, GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == GridViewEditAction.Commit && handle)
    {
        handle = false;
        gridView.CommitEdit();
        handle = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely got rid of the error thankfully. However, now the edit is not committed and anything I add into a cell disappears as I click out of it which is weird.  I'll do some extra research into it, but thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

> ActionOnLostFocus="CommitEdit"

for your radgridview tag